# C#/sql changing sql parameter with swl parameter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, forms

I have a problem with using SQL in c# form and I hope someone can help me here is codes and I wrote as !!!HERE!!! to row of problem.

I want to check textboxes and if they are empty i'll put old variables to updating function but I couldn't make equalization between old and new command.parameters

```
     private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sql = "Update faculty SET fcode=@fcode,fname=@fname,foundationdate=@foundationdate WHERE fcode=@fcodeold";
            try
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fcode", textBox1.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", textBox2.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@foundationdate", dateTimePicker1.Value);

                command.Connection = connection;
              //  command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM faculty WHERE fcode=@fcode";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fcodeold", dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fnameold", dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@foundationdateold", dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                if (textBox1.Text =="") command.Parameters.["@fcode"].Value= command.Parameters.("@fcodeold").Value;

    //!!!HERE!!!
                if (textBox2.Text == "") command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", "@fnameold");
                if (dateTimePicker1 == null) command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@foundationdate", "@foundationdateold");
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Updating success", "Updated", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                FormFaculty_Load(null, null);
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This question could really use some cleanup and formatting. It is really hard to follow.

Comment: Slightly off topic but you should check out this article. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: And really? TextBox1, dataGridView1 etc...put some effort into naming your controls and your life will be a lot easier.

Comment: thank you sean for share the article and your command i ll try to change my coding habbits but im new with this coding stuffs I have started just 3 mounts before and i have lots of things which I ll learn..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying to set the parameter like this?:

```
command.Parameters.["@fcode"].Value = command.Parameters.("@fcodeold").Value
```

You already *have* the "value", because you used it earlier:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fcodeold", dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString())
```

Just set this parameter the same way:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fcode", dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString())
```

Don't try to set values from within the query.  You have the data in one place, and the query in another.  Set the query values from the data.

---

To summarize:

Remove where you set the parameter earlier in the code:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fcode", textBox1.Text); // remove this line
```

and conditionally set the parameter based on your logic:

```
if (textBox1.Text =="")
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fcode", dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString())
else
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fcode", textBox1.Text)
```

Comment: Yes  I think I'm confused thank you,but anyway if you know how it's possible to equelization between parameters can you share this too?.It's not for this example but it can be usefull somewhere..

Comment: @arricie: It's not clear what you mean by that.  What is "to equalization between parameters"?

Comment: @a=@b;  likely that it doesnt accept ,i mean how can add value to 1 sql variable from another sql variable in c#

Comment: @arricie sql variables can be handled this way in sql: you are working in c# so you fill the (reference to a) sql variable using the same c# object twice.

Comment: @arricie: In that context it looks like `@a` should be an identifier in the query, not a parameterized value.  Query identifiers (column names, table names, etc.) can't be parameters, only values can.  It's not clear why you would need to do that.

Comment: Yes you right I thought these are comes as variables like integer and what that column has,Ok you  informed to me much thank you..